# Javascript Vs Css specificity Vs inline-Styling

Tags: javascript, css

My question is a short one.Does javasript overwrites inline Styling ?.Furthermore I know it overwrites css styling with any level of specificity but would javascript still be able to overwrite css even if I add the !important flag ?

Comment: Maybe try some code and see what happens?

Comment: JavaScript can create and add stylesheets as well as change inline styles. Comparing css to javascript here is improper. JavaScript can do anything you can do by hand. If you're curious about the order by which browser decides what styles should be applied, you should google css cascade.

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) states the following:

> The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the
>   inline style of an element.

So yes it does overwrite inline styling. You can see that yourself when you do a inspection of the DOM.

As you can see in below snippet, Javascript wins over Inline CSS because you overwrite the Inline CSS. Inline CSS wins over CSS because it's the most specific.

However the `!important` flag will overrule more specific CSS rules that don't have the important flag.

```js
document.querySelector('#javascript').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
document.querySelector('#important').style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
}

div#important {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="javascript" style="background-color: lightgreen;">javascript</div>
<div id="inline" style="background-color: lightgreen;">inline</div>
<div id="css">css</div>
<div id="important" style="background-color: lightgreen;">important!</div>
```

**Note:** `!important` flag should be avoided as much as possible. Most often there is a better solution. Why do you consider using it?

Answer (score 0):

`Element.prototype.style` overrides the inline styling for that element (the `style` atttribute) and yes, it does overwrite CSS styling with any level of specificity (CSS inside `<style>` blocks).

However, the `!important` flag does take precedence over inline styling.

Comment: you can add `!important` to inline styles. *!important inline style* has the highest priority.